# Bubbling events within custom components in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a custom component within another custom component in a flex mxml application file.Is it possible to bubble events from an inner component to the outer component and handle events in the outer component?

Answer (score 4):

The [`Event`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html) constructor defaults the `bubbles` parameter to `false` so, as [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040610/bubbling-events-within-custom-components-in-flex/2040742#2040742) mentions, you need to set `bubbles` to `true` when you construct the event.

Once bubbling is enabled, the event will continue to be dispatched up the UI tree until [Event.stopPropagation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation()) or [Event.stopImmediatePropagation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation()) is called.

Keep in mind, though, that bubbling only affects UI components; events fired from custom classes will not bubble, even if the `bubbles` argument is set to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes just set the property `bubbles` to true into you inner component when dispatching:

**inner component:**

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("myEvent", true));
```

**outer component:**

```
addEventListener("myEvent", onMyEvent);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Outer.mxml
<local:Inner id="inner"/>
inner.addEventListener(TYPE_NAME, handler);
private function handler(e:Event):void
{
    trace("Bingo");
}

//Inner.mxml
dispatchEvent(new Event(TYPE_NAME));
```